# REST resource naming for an unique resource

Tags: rest, naming-conventions

I have a resource that is basically an aggregation of all the thing accessible by the current (authenticated) user. Let's call it `Workspace`.

**Given that there is always one and only one `Workspace` per user**:

Should I apply the "plural" convention ? If yes, should I create a fake sub-resource to signify that it is unique ?

In other words, should I use :

- `/workspace` -> The current user workspace

Or

- `/workspaces/~` -> The current user workspace
- `/workspaces` -> 404

For a user perspective, it makes sense to have one unique `/workspace` resource. 
However from the system point of view there are many workspaces but only one per user, so `/workspaces/~` looks more logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any hard and fast rules here. I'd say use whatever is going to make sense to your end-user, and preferably is consistent with what you're doing elsewhere.

For example, there are some other addresses that come to mind, depending on how your website works. If a workspace is tied to a user, then maybe it makes sense to have it under the `/users/{id}/workspaces` address. Maybe this doesn't make sense for your case though. So among the options you gave, I'd say if it's obvious to the client that there ought to be multiple workspaces but they only have access to one, then the `/workspaces/{id}` address would fit that model. If it appears them that a workspace is a unique entity, then having the plural address might be confusing.

In my own designs I tend to err toward the direction of using plurals for everything.